# the small space is missing in bootstrap between form-groups

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

On my site the space is missing between the form-groups.
However I am using the bootstrap-sass gem and the Chrome console shows no errors.
I also tried with bootstrap.min.css instead of bootstrap-sass. And the space is missing too.

I also compared the css properties of form-groups from my site with the one on the bootstrap example site and I found them similar.

What could cause the missing space? (The horizontal margin is 0 in both cases.)

[image]

[image]

https://github.com/orbanbotond/bootstrap_exercise
http://bootstrap-exercise.herokuapp.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That space is generated by the property `inline-block`, normally you want to [avoid that space](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) using some of this techniques:

- Set `font-size` to 0.
- Set a negative margin usually `margin-right:-4px`

But in this case since you aren't adding any extra CSS I guess you are removing the space between the tags on the HTML like:

```
<div class="form-group"></div><div class="form-group"></div>
```

Instead of

```
<div class="form-group"></div>
<div class="form-group"></div>
```

That will delete the space between `inline-block` elements.

Check this [**BootplyDemo**](http://www.bootply.com/B22g8O3haU)

Comment: I see now the reason. Since I was using slim template that generated a compact html without spaces... Thx BTW

Comment: That is @Boti glad to help U understand the issue